# Reactivity of KOH with PVC

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, home-experiment

I Would like to know if its possible to get a reaction between KOH at ~50% (w/w) and an usual PVC pipe? If yes what kind?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just curious for practical purposes (i.e., "Can I put this KOH solution in this PVC container or will it ruin it?"), there are many material compatibility tables for this type of thing. [This one](https://www.spilltech.com/wcsstore/SpillTechUSCatalogAssetStore/Attachment/documents/ccg/CBOOM.pdf) suggests that your solution will be OK at low temperatures for a few days at least. It may react after more time or at higher temperatures.

If you want to know specifically about the chemistry, KOH is a strong base. [Strong bases are known to crack polymer chains through solvolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemically_assisted_degradation_of_polymers#Degradation_of_poly.28vinyl.29_chloride_.28PVC.29). PVC in particular loses some chlorine atoms to the solvent which weakens and ultimately shortens the polymer chains, as explained in more detail in the link.